# How to create ODataNavigationLink when using ODataLib entry writer?

Tags: odata, odatalib

I am trying to find an example of how to properly instantiate ODataNavigationLink in case it's non-empty. The only code example I've found creates a non-expanded link but doesn't bind it to any data:

```
//create a non-expanded link for the orders navigation property
  writer.WriteStart(new ODataNavigationLink()
  {
      IsCollection = true,
      Name = "Orders",
      Url = new Uri("http://microsoft.com/Customer(" + 
                 dataSource.Customers.First().CustomerID + ")/Orders")
  });
  writer.WriteEnd(); //ends the orders link
```

So here we specify the link to "Orders". But how do I provide the actual values for the link (in this example the link is a collection but it can also be a single entry). When I was writing the payload manually I was providing "href" attribute with a linked entry ID. I can't figure out how this is done with ODataLib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value appear in the 'href' attribute just shows the Url property of ODataNavigationLink, so you can try the following code to set it manually:

```
//create a non-expanded link for the orders navigation property
writer.WriteStart(new ODataNavigationLink() { 
    IsCollection = true,
    Name = "Orders",
    Url = new Uri("http://microsoft.com/Orders(3)") }); 
writer.WriteEnd(); //ends the orders link
```

In common, the navigation link should be the source entity url followed by the navigation property,see [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-atom-format/v4.0/cs02/odata-atom-format-v4.0-cs02.html#_Toc372792728), while id should point to the real entry ID.

**updated:**

According to the latest feedback, you're trying to write the 'Collection of links' as described in section 14.1 of the [atom spec](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/atom-format). Thus you can try ODataEntityReferenceLinks class:

```
var referenceLink1 = new ODataEntityReferenceLink { Url = new Uri("http://host/Orders(1)") };
var referenceLink2 = new ODataEntityReferenceLink { Url = new Uri("http://host/Orders(2)") };
var referenceLink3 = new ODataEntityReferenceLink { Url = new Uri("http://host/Orders(3)") };
var referenceLinks = new ODataEntityReferenceLinks
{
    Links = new[] { referenceLink1, referenceLink2, referenceLink3 }
};
writer.WriteEntityReferenceLinks(referenceLinks);
```

and the payload would be something like:

```
<links xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
  <uri>http://host/Orders(1)</uri>
  <uri>http://host/Orders(2)</uri>
  <uri>http://host/Orders(3)</uri>
</links>
```

Comment: Hmm, but the "Orders" is a collection, how do I specify multiple items? By setting up multiple links? I think I already tried something like this and it didn't work. I will check it again.

Comment: Can you show the actual payload you expect here? If it is something like this [link](http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products%281%29/$links/Categories), you can try ODataEntityReferenceLinks class, and then use writer.WriteEntityReferenceLinks.

Comment: Yes, I think ODataEntityReferenceLink is the way to go. I tried a small sample and I am getting "href" attribute to be set to a referenced entity key. I'll do more testing.

Comment: If you edit your answer and add a reference to ODataEntityReferenceLink, I will accept it as the answer, 'cause this is what I need.